# skype web sdk login failed says "cannot sign in TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null"

Tags: sdk, skype, skype-for-business

i hope everyone is doing well.
here i am stuck with something that you guys can help me out.
i am using skype web sdk sample code from [GitHub] (http://github/tomorgan/SkypeWebSDKSamples/tree/gh-pages).
i am trying to login using any credentials i got the same error. 
Type Error: Cannot read property '1' of null.

what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Skype's API; an issue is logged here:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/issues/338

The problem is that Skype's SDK is expecting a username of the format `name@domain`, and doesn't handle any other case.